# Generate a NumPy 1D array with a pre-specified correlation with an existing 1D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a non-generated 1D NumPy array. For now, we will use a generated one.

```py
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.random.uniform(0, 100, 1_000)
```

I need an array that will be correlated `0.3` with it:

```py
arr2 = '?'
print(np.corrcoef(arr1, arr2))
```

```
Out[1]: 0.3
```

Comment: Are there any other constraints on the distribution of `arr2`?

Comment: Nope. Preferably on the same scale as arr1 though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adapted [this answer by whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/313138) on stats.SE to NumPy. The idea is to generate a second array `noise` randomly, and then compute the residuals of a least-squares linear regression of `noise` on `arr1`. The residuals necessarily have a correlation of 0 with `arr1`, and of course `arr1` has a correlation of 1 with itself, so an appropriate linear combination of `a*arr1 + b*residuals` will have any desired correlation.

```py
import numpy as np

def generate_with_corrcoef(arr1, p):
    n = len(arr1)

    # generate noise
    noise = np.random.uniform(0, 1, n)

    # least squares linear regression for noise = m*arr1 + c
    m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(np.vstack([arr1, np.ones(n)]).T, noise)[0]

    # residuals have 0 correlation with arr1
    residuals = noise - (m*arr1 + c)

    # the right linear combination a*arr1 + b*residuals
    a = p * np.std(residuals)
    b = (1 - p**2)**0.5 * np.std(arr1)

    arr2 = a*arr1 + b*residuals

    # return a scaled/shifted result to have the same mean/sd as arr1
    # this doesn't change the correlation coefficient
    return np.mean(arr1) + (arr2 - np.mean(arr2)) * np.std(arr1) / np.std(arr2)
```

The last line scales the result so that the mean and standard deviation are the same as `arr1`'s. However, `arr1` and `arr2` will not be identically distributed.

Usage:

```py
>>> arr1 = np.random.uniform(0, 100, 1000)
>>> arr2 = generate_with_corrcoef(arr1, 0.3)
>>> np.corrcoef(arr1, arr2)
array([[1. , 0.3],
       [0.3, 1. ]])
```